# Can't move email into another folder error 438 Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to mark an email with a specific subject as read and move it to another folder. The error is on the line `.UnRead = False`.

This line is causing the error 438. I have tried different combinations of `myitem` with the same result.

```
    Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
    Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim OutlookMail As Variant
    Dim DestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim RetiredFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim myItem As Object
    Dim myItems As Outlook.MailItem


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Emails")
    Set wsNS = wb.Worksheets("NS_Export")
    ws.Activate
    Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.Folders("myemail").Folders("NOC Announcements New")
    Set RetiredFolder = OutlookNamespace.Folders("tmyemail").Folders("Retired Buildings")

    For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items

            Set myItem = Folder.Items.Find("[Subject] = 'The following building has been permanently retired'")
                            With myItem
                            .UnRead = False
                            .Move RetiredFolder
                        End With

        Next OutlookMail
```

Comment: You probably have an item that's not a `MailItem`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78924/when-is-a-mailitem-not-a-mailitem

Comment: Should I switch outlook.MailItem to something else?

Comment: No (because you're using `myItem`, which is an `Object`, not `myItems`, which you don't use at all).

Comment: `On Error Resume Next`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49069849/treating-item-as-mailitem is one option. There are perhaps better ones too.

Comment: I don't want to skip the error, I would like to find out what is causing it. I need the identified ematil to be moved.

Comment: The item is not a mailitem. That's the error.

Comment: You're not using `OutlookMail` at all in your loop... This may be a case to use [`Items.Restrict`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.restrict).

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
Dim outlookmail As Outlook.MailItem
    For Each outlookmail In Folder.Items
        If TypeOf outlookmail Is MailItem Then
        If outlookmail.Subject = "The following building has been permanently retired" Then
        With outlookmail
            .UnRead = False
            .Move RetiredFolder
        End With
        End If
        End If
    Next outlookmail
```

Comment: I added  your suggestion            the item is recognized as a mailitem and I still get the error 438

Comment: Can you tell, which line of code produces the error ?

Comment: @ShivangGupta - OP never uses `OutlookMail` in the loop, but rather `myItem`.

Comment: I had to truncate my code to enter the question I forget to add the line right after For each OutlookMail in Folder.Items          Set myItem = Folder.Items.Find("[Subject] = 'The following building has been permanently retired'")

Comment: If you were to use this looping approach, then you'd use `If OutlookMail.Subject = ...`. @user2576682.

Comment: I have               strSubject = OutlookMail.Subject
                Debug.Print strSubject
'                Stop
            Set myItem = Folder.Items
            If strSubject = "The following building has been permanently retired" Then

Comment: may be you will get some idea from above updated code. Run it and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you the proposed code change worked, Thanks! great job