# How to run a macro that requires an argument "myitem As Outlook.mailItem"?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have this:

```
Public Sub MoveMails (myitem As Outlook.mailItem)
...
End Sub
```

Runs automatically from a rule when I receive a new email.

I want launch this when I want. I tried with `Call MoveMails` but I don't know the argument for `myitem As Outlook.mailItem`.

---

I receive several mails. My idea is to move all. I have several conditions: filter by subject, body... and I move them to different folders.

Answer (score 0):

I found a sub for selecting the current item [here](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/outlook-vba-work-with-open-item-or-select-item/) - it has options for whether the item is open in it's own window (inspector) or in the main Outlook window (explorer).

I recommend you add the custom function `GetCurrentItem()` from that page to your module and use that as your `myitem` parameter.

So to call the MoveMails sub `Call Movemails(GetCurrentItem())`.

```vb
Function GetCurrentItem() As Object
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
           
    Set objApp = Application
    On Error Resume Next
    Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
        Case "Explorer"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
        Case "Inspector"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    End Select
       
    Set objApp = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: I have another doubt... It's no works for run macro in several mails, you know... only for last I received... or one mail. I don't know why... I received several mails in my Inbox, and my idea is run the macro and move all at the same time (those who fulfil the conditions). I hace several conditions: filter by subject, body... and I move them in different folders.

Comment: That's because the `GetCurrentItem' function is only made to select one email at a time. If you select (or open) the items individually and run the macro on each it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I know you wish to run this on multiple items at once.

Remove the parameter `(myitem As Outlook.MailItem)` from the sub to run on all items in the folder, or in a selection.

Copied from the code you posted (I've changed the formatting a bit too);

```vb
Public Sub Corrected()

'==========================================
'Declare variables:
Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder
Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder
'Set variables:
Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Folders("CHECK")
'===========================================

'Declare the variable MyItem but don't set it:
Dim MyItem As Outlook.MailItem


'Create a loop for all items in a certain folder:
For Each MyItem In myInbox 'Or for a subfolder use '...In MyInbox.Folders("FolderName")'

'Or to check selected items you could use the below:
'For Each MyItem in Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection

    'if body contains alarm then move
     If InStr(MyItem.Body, "alarm") > 0 Then
        MyItem.Move myDestFolder
     End If
    
    'if subject contains Urgent move
     If InStr(MyItem.Subject, "Urgent") > 0 Then
        MyItem.Move myDestFolder
     End If
    
    'if body contains MASTER then categorize
     If InStr(MyItem.Body, "MASTER") > 0 Then
        MyItem.Categories = "Boss"
        MyItem.Save
    End If

Next MyItem 'This loops onto the next item in the selection or folder,
             'so it checks them all automatically.

End Sub
```

Comment: Not all items will be mailitems. Other types will not necessarily have the expected mailitem property. `Dim myItem as Object` then test whether that object is a mailitem. One method shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49069849/treating-item-as-mailitem