# Select email messages from a sender

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I'm trying to save all mails from a certain sender with certain words in the subject as txt file and delete it.

When the code hits the `If Item.Sender.Address = "john@xxx.com"` I get an error

> property or method not supported by object

```vb
Private Sub Spedizioni()
  
    Dim objNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim sourceFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim Msg As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sName As String
    Dim sPath As String
            
    sPath = "C:\Mail\"

    Set objNamespace = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set sourceFolder = objNamespace.Folders("Spareparts").Folders("Inbox")
    Set Items = sourceFolder.Items

    For i = 1 To Items.Count
        
        Set Item = Items.Item(i)
        DoEvents
        
        If Item.Sender.Address = "john@xxx.com" And Item.To = "michael@yyy.com" And Left(Item.Subject, 4) = "EXPR" Then
            sName = Item.Subject
            sName = Format(Item.ReceivedTime, "yyyymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & Format(Item.ReceivedTime, "-hhnnss", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & "-" & sName & ".txt"
            Item.SaveAs sPath & sName
            Item.Delete
        End If
    Next
       
End Sub
```

Comment: "not working" is not very useful in helping us diagnose the exact problem you're having...

Comment: Hi Tim, you're right, sorry!!
When the code gets to
 If Item.Sender.Address = "john@xxx.com"......
I get a "Property or method not supported by object" message.

I'll edit the main text

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Treating Item As MailItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49069849/treating-item-as-mailitem)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `sName` is constructed from `MailItem.Subject`,  which can include characters invalid in file names, such as `":"`, etc. Secondly, do not loop through all items in a folder - use `Items.Restrict` or `Items.Find/FindNext`.

Comment: Hi Dmitry,
I'll put a replacechars sub to avoid invalid characters.
And will look to items.restrict or items.find

Howeved as I edited in the main text my main proble is that the code does not run at all.

Thanks again

Comment: It will not run if you just create a sub with nothing calling it. When is it supposed to be called?

Comment: I've took this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257985/outlook-vba-run-a-code-every-half-an-hour to run it every 5 minute

Comment: So the problem is that the timer does not kick in for whatever reason? Or that your OOM code does not work? In the former case, you really need to work with your timer code first.

Answer (score 0):

I've got to a solution. Probably not the most elegant (and corrections about it are appreciated) but it's working.

```vb
Private Sub Spedizioni()
  
    Dim objNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim sourceFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sName As String
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim Filter As String
            
    sPath = "C:\Mail\"

    Set objNamespace = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set sourceFolder = objNamespace.Folders("Spareparts").Folders("Inbox")
    Set Items = sourceFolder.Items

Filter = "@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:displayto"" ci_phrasematch '%john@xxx.com%' and ""urn:schemas:httpmail:subject"" ci_phrasematch '%Spares%'"
Set Items = Items.Restrict(Filter)


    For i = 1 To Items.Count
        
        Set Item = Items.Item(i)
        DoEvents
        
        sName = Item.Subject
        sName = Format(Item.ReceivedTime, "yyyymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & Format(Item.ReceivedTime, "-hhnnss", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & "-" & sName & ".txt"
        sName = Replace(sName, "/", "_")
        sName = Replace(sName, "\", "_")
        sName = Replace(sName, ":", "_")
        sName = Replace(sName, "?", "_")
        sName = Replace(sName, Chr(34), "_")
        sName = Replace(sName, "<", "_")
        sName = Replace(sName, ">", "_")
        sName = Replace(sName, "|", "_")
            
        Item.SaveAs sPath & sName, olTXT
        Item.Delete

    Next
       
End Sub
```

Comment: Consider `Option Explicit` mandatory. There is no `oMail`.

Comment: Thanks Niton, oMail was there since an older version of the code and I left it commented to test it...
I've edited the messege and corrected it for future usage.